# UIWebView not loading mobile version of site with loadRequest

Tags: ios, mobile, uiwebview

I'm trying to use a UIWebView to embed a mobile version of a site in my app.  However, when I do the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webLink];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

the full version of the site is loaded.  Then when I click any of the links in this page, it will process the mobile version of the site (as I would like it to from the very beginning).

I've tried messing around with the user-agent, with no luck.  I don't think it's looking at the user-agent to determine whether or not to load the mobile version of the page, because I set my Firefox user-agent to iPhone and it still proceeded to load the full version.

If it helps any, the site I'm trying to load is a message board, using IP Board 3.1.4. I tried looking online to see how it determines whether or not to display mobile versions, with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem today.

I posted my problem on the IP Board support forum, and got a response back saying that the IP Board checks for either "iPhone" in the user-agent, or a "mobileApp" cookie.  Since messing with the user-agent wasn't working for me, I went with the latter approach.

I put this code into my applicationDidBecomeActive method in my appdelegate:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"mobileApp" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"1" forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"www.example.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"www.example.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieOriginURL];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"/" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"0" forKey:NSHTTPCookieVersion];

NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
```

PS: I found this cookie solution in another stackoverflow question about cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If the website does not have a full mobile version, there's NOTHING you can do. :(

Comment: No, it does have a mobile version. It's just the mobile version isn't getting loaded when I do a loadRequest on the web view.  As soon as I click a link in this webview, it will load the correct mobile version.

Comment: I still think it's a issue with the website you're trying to load.

Comment: Okay, but when I load the home page in safari, it goes right to the mobile site, unlike what happens in the webview. I feel like I need to do something special to construct the request so that it knows to load the mobile site right away.

Comment: Safari probably sends some http headers you're not sending. I'd create a page to retrieve the headers Safari sends, so you would know what you're not sending.

Comment: Any idea how to do this through safari? I looked at it through my web view, and indeed the second time it loaded (in the mobile view) I saw some meta tags for iPhone. Is there any way I can just inject these into my request?