# Open Mobile Site on iPad WebView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to load the mobile version of a site in a UIWebView on an iPad but I can only get it to load the desktop version. Am i doing something wrong?

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http:www.kyfbnewsroom.com/2013-kentucky-farm-bureau-annual-meeting-program/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [requestObj setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: One issue is `http:www.kyfbnewsroom.com....` should be `http://www.kyfbnewsroom.com...`

Comment: Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542038/uiwebview-not-loading-mobile-version-of-site-with-loadrequest

Comment: This could either be your navigate code or the fact that your side doesn't have a mobile/responsive version. Are you certain that one exists?

Comment: @Popeye, yes there is a mobile version. That version loads on the iPhone.

Comment: @ppolak, the accepted answer to that question did not work.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /home/kyfbnews/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wptouch/core/mobile-user-agents.php on line 18 :) @ http:www.kyfbnewsroom.com ....

Comment: I know. I was editing something and now this is happening.